# How to transfer data between two separate scripts in Multiprocessing?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, communication

I am using multiprocessing to run two python scripts in parallel. p1.y continually updates a certain variable and the latest value of the variable will be displayed by p2.py after every 2seconds. The code for multiprocessing of the two scripts are given below:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

def script1():
    os.system("p1.py")
def script2():
    os.system("p2.py")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=script1)
    q = Process(target=script2)
    p.start()
    q.start()
    p.join()
    q.join()
```

I am unable to transfer the value of the variable being updated by p1.py to p2.py. How should I approach the problem in a very simple way?

Comment: The real question here is how to extract the output of a command running inside `os.system`. [Here's an explanation of the communication between processes](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html)

Comment: Have you any background in computer science? What do you know about concurrency paradigms, processes, threads, coroutines, etc? i.e. why processes? Chosen for a specific reason? They might not be the right solution

Comment: For sharing data between 2 separate processes, a good approach would be to set up a message queue. ZeroMQ is one such fast and efficient message queue.

Comment: My main objective is to run both codes in parallel. I am new to python and I do not possess much knowledge in computer Science background. I require it for a project I am working on.